# Joomla 3.5.1 Asking for article when seperate component view is selected

Tags: view, joomla, menu, components

Hello i'm having an issue where a component is asking for an article linked after i select a part of the component, and it's not allowing me to save the menu item.

Originally i thought this might be in admin->component->modals but that would determine what shows on the component item forms not the menu selection. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I dont know about this component but as per the error you need to select an article which you have not selected. So where its given select article* just select an article and the error will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

I think i've found this according to this document: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_a_menu_type_to_the_site_part

Thanks to anyone who would like to add information.